# CSS rotate function. How to specify the direction of spinning?

Tags: css, animation, rotation, direction

Consider this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s2Lngpto/1/

I have a spinner, and I would like it to spin every time not 360 degrees around but 315 degrees (and go in full cycle in 8 rotations), and CSS is behaving really weirdly. From what I understood, if you specify for example `rotate(315deg)`, it should move to the position -45 degrees of the current position. But instead if moves through the longest path to the right. Okay.. I guess that's just how CSS works, if you specify positive integers it will rotate right, if negative - left? Right... right?
Nope, I've specified the position 270 degrees, and on the second stage it rotates left instead of right

Am I doing something wrong? What is the easiest way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can simply define negative values

Answer (score 0):

As u have awnsered yourself:

- in one direction(right):
  `transform: rotate(10deg)`
- in the other direction(left):
  `transform: rotate(-10deg)`

It probably has to do with your animation, when you have the attribute `animation: alternate` for example it tends to do as u described. Could u provide some code?